# Replace fieldnames when using DictReader

Tags: python, json, csv, etl

I have a `test.csv` file:

```
foo,bar,foobar,barfoo

1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
```

And the following `CSV` parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import json

f = open ( 'test.csv', 'r' )

reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ( "foo","bar","foobar","barfoo" ))

out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ], ensure_ascii=False, encoding="utf-8")

print out
```

Is there an easy way to replace the fieldnames in the output, without changing the header of the `CSV` file?

My current output is this:

```
[
   {
      "foobar":"foobar",
      "foo":"foo",
      "bar":"bar",
      "barfoo":"barfoo"
   },
   {
      "foobar":"3",
      "foo":"1",
      "bar":"2",
      "barfoo":"4"
   },
   {
      "foobar":"7",
      "foo":"5",
      "bar":"6",
      "barfoo":"8"
   },
   {
      "foobar":"11",
      "foo":"9",
      "bar":"10",
      "barfoo":"12"
   }
]
```

Could I get something like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"foobar",
      "email":"foo",
      "name":"bar",
      "phone":"barfoo"
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "email":"1",
      "name":"2",
      "phone":"4"
   },
   {
      "id":"7",
      "email":"5",
      "name":"6",
      "phone":"8"
   },
   {
      "id":"11",
      "email":"9",
      "name":"10",
      "phone":"12"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way is to just set:

```
reader.fieldnames = "email", "name", "id",  "phone"
```

You can save the old fieldnames if you want too.

Comment: Oh. So the `fieldnames` don't have to correspond with the actual `fieldnames` of the header line in the `CSV`?

Comment: @cherrun No they don't. On a side note, You don't even need to specify them like you did. `csv.DictReader(f)` will read the first line as the header by default, without need for `fieldnames=...` but maybe it's better the way you have it

Answer (score 11):

Just replace this line:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames = ( "foo","bar","foobar","barfoo" ))
```

with this:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=("id", "email", "name", "phone"))
```

Comment: Note that the fieldnames argument provides a header for your data. If the argument is omitted, it will be taken from the first row of your csv file.